# Blank screen after installing ubuntu on flash drive and booting it from computer with Windows 10 preinstalled

Tags: system-installation, secure-boot

After installing ubuntu on a flash drive and setting the bios to load OS from that drive, I boot to a blank screen.
 After a minute or so Windows will boot from the hard drive.
 I am working with an Asus gl552v, nvidia gtx 960m, Windows 10 installed.

This is my first time setting up ubuntu, or any OS really I am very new to this, any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If your PC has UEFI/Secureboot enabled, it can *as it should* ignore USB devices as bootable media.

Windows then boots when it decides not to trust a USB peripheral.

Comment: you should mention ways to work around this problem

Comment: It's highly machine dependent.  So, not so easy for a universal answer/workaround.  Disable UEFI is simplest, but that's a dupe answer from somewhere.